# Sum of field in related object

Tags: apex, soql

I have an eshot object which is related to Lead.

For each lead `myLead`
I would like to sum into `myLead.clicks`
the integer `eshot.numclicks__c`
where `eshot.lead__c` matches the current lead.

My SOQL is weak. How could I do this?

Comment: How is it "related", is it through a master-detail? If so you can look into the roll-up summary fields perhaps if that suits your use case. It is a bit difficult to understand your question as it is now. If roll-up summary fields does not meet your criteria you could look into writing a trigger fo this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not master-detail. The master is Email-definition which generates detail Email-result records (eshots in my question) Each Email-result links to a Lead. I can see how I can count these via trigger but I need to account for existing data. I would basically loop through my eshots and run the trigger code I guess.

Comment: My eshots results are generated by ExactTarget.

Comment: Then I would assume that you would need to write the Trigger and then creating a script that you run in the environments where you should update the existing data (forcing the trigger to run på making for example a dummy update of the objects that the Trigger triggers on) so that you are "up to date". Creating and running the script from the developer console should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your triggers and backfill batch all without writing any code yourself if you install [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). Just create a `Lookup Rollup Summary` as follows:

- Parent Object: `Lead`
- Child Object: `EShot__c`
- Relationship Field: `Lead__c`
- Field to Aggregate: `NumClicks__c`
- Aggregate Operation: `Sum`
- Aggregate Result Field: `Clicks__c`

Comment: That is very nice but there is no installation documentation.

Comment: @Dizzley A simple search on the page for the word "install" would work for you. Or just click [here](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries#user-content-packaged-release-history)...

Comment: @Dizzley Were you able to try this solution?

Comment: Did you try searching for "install" on the page? The link provided there "Packaging and Installing Rollups" doesn't work, but redirects to top of page.I tried it before saying there was no installation instructions. There are 12 instances of the word "install".  None of them tell you how to install the package. Your own link shows text with the packages on SF but that is not an installation instruction. If you know that clicking the package URL will take you to the installation you are OK. If not...

Comment: Thanks, I have now tried the DLRS package. It is excellent. I have some rollups in place now. I would prefer some more control on scheduling rollup calculations but otherwise it's great. (I have been busy lately on other tasks).